# What can we say about the probability a strategy losing money in a year if it has an annualized Sharpe of say 2?

Tags: sharpe-ratio

If we imposed the restriction that the strategy is not skewed, then using Chebyshev's Inequality I can show that the probability of it losing money in a year is less than 12.5%.

Let $X$ be the yearly PnL of a strategy. Let $\mathbf{E}(X) = \mu$ and $\mathbf{Var}(X)=\sigma$. We know that $\frac{\mu}{\sigma} = 2$.

Then, $\mathbf{P}(X < 0) = \mathbf{P}(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} < -2) = \mathbf{P}(Z < -2) = 0.5\mathbf{P}(|Z| > 2)$. The last equality makes use of the fact that $X$ is not skewed. Then, by Chebyshev's Inequality, $\mathbf{P}(|Z| > 2) < \frac{1}{2^2}$. Therefore, $\mathbf{P}(X < 0) < 0.125$.

Is there a tighter bound to this problem?

Comment: I think in practical terms, you might as well assume a normal distribution for this, since you say the returns aren't skewed.

Comment: How do you derive $P(|Z| > 2) < 1/4$ by Chebyshev's inequality?  Are you told $E[|Z|] = 1$?

Comment: @TickaJules Skew might be zero, but kurtosis is certainly much higher in practice than a normal distribution. What we can say is that a normal distribution establishes a lower bound. If assuming a normal distribution, then the probability is about 0.025.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Why is it necessary to know the mean? Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality.

Comment: @Student I see, by your definition, $\operatorname{Var}(Z) = 1$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong that is right.

Comment: The best way to get these bounds would be to look for more concentration inequalities, e.g. under more restrictive assumptions on returns. For example, if the distribution of returns is unimodal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vysochanskij%E2%80%93Petunin_inequality

Comment: If all we have are the mean and the variance of returns, along with your symmetry assumption, then we cannot say more, because the distribution that achieves equality in Chebyshev's inequality satisfies all the above.

Answer (score -1):

Sure. With 0 rfr and assuming independent and normally distributed returns that’s equivalent to taking N(-2) which is ≈ 2.275%.

Comment: I don't want to assume normally distributed return because that is unrealistic in practice. Even a t-distribution is unrealistic. But N(-2) does set a lower bound for the problem (t-distribution would set an even larger (and better) lower bound). One can try constructing examples with fat-tail distributions that increase $\mathbf{P}(X < 0)$. The question is what is the largest this can get, and I have shown in my question that this cannot be larger than 0.125.